# Dragging a div into a table and getting the id of cell

Tags: jquery, draggable

I am trying to alert the id of a table cell that I am dragging something into.  I've cobbled various examples together and although I think I'm close I'm not quite there.  Any pointers gratefully received thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

    $('.drop').droppable({
        accept: ".nodrop",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        snap: ".drop",


  }
  drop: function (event, ui) {
            var parenttd = $(ui.draggable).closest('td').attr('id');

 alert("parenttd=" + parenttd);

  );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<br /><br />
<table style="width:600px;" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="1" align="middle"><h1>1</h1></td>
    <td id="2" align="middle"><h1>2</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3" align="middle"><h1>3</h1></td>
    <td id="4" align="middle"><h1>4</h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), please

Comment: Add a Fiddle please.

Comment: Or a Stack Snippet: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Hello - I have set up a Fiddle account and posted my code here:  http://jsfiddle.net/edmozley/v3cwttgr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are many errors in your js code.

Here is very well explained: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

This would be a solution for your problem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  #droppable td{ width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();

    $('#droppable td').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var parenttd  = $(this).attr('id');
            alert("parenttd=" + parenttd);
        }

  })
});


  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

<br /><br />
<table id="droppable" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="1" align="middle"><h1>1</h1></td>
    <td id="2" align="middle"><h1>2</h1></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="3" align="middle"><h1>3</h1></td>
    <td id="4" align="middle"><h1>4</h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - however when I drop the div into a cell it alerts the id of the table not the cell.

Comment: I will have a look at jsfiddle - I have not used this before and come back once I have done that

Comment: oh, sorry I understood that you wanted the id of the table, not of the cell.

in that case you just need to change that line:
......
    $('#droppable td').droppable({
.......

:)

Comment: Thanks Jorge this is really, really helpful.  I find this example much easier to understand than anything else I have seen so far.  One final question if I may - if I want to alert the id of the div that was dropped is this possible? e.g. it would say "Droppable was dropped in to box 1"

Comment: Success! After a bit more searching I found someone else had a similar problem.  I have now used alert(ui.draggable.prop('id') + ' was dropped into box' + parenttd);